# What combinations of motor and control strategy are compatible with high static holding torques?

Tags: motor-controller

I am aware of permanent magnet motors, synchronous motors, induction motors, and stepping motors, as well as frequency control, vector control and stepping control. Servomotors and controllers are a separate category again.

My assumption is that stepping and servomotors are designed to hold static position torques, and other solutions are either not good at the task or the controllers would not be designed to allow it.

What considerations are there on motor and controller selection that ensure static torque holding functionality on a new build? What parameters in a controller ensure it has the feature(s) required?

Comment: There's also the [cogging torque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogging_torque) which has the advantage of requiring zero energy to hold a position.

Comment: Mechanical brakes are an option.

Comment: Consider a gearbox, especially with a worm gear.  But this site is only for *answerably specific* questions, not broad "survey" ones.  To have an allowable question, you'll need to be **specific about your exact problem and requirement**, to discuss technologies *in general* you need a traditional *discussion forum* or to list them, something like a *wiki* - neither of which are what this site is.  It may also be that this is really more of a mechnical engineering problem than an electrical engineering one...

Answer (score 0):

One specification might be ‘rms torque’. This is the average amount of torque the motor can generate without getting too hot.
There are other means of providing a holding torque - a solenoid brake is one method.

Comment: thanks for that. I have considered the static brake, but this has the limitation of not being good at handling a slow takeoff and requires an external torque cell to measure the static torque.

Comment: @J Collins this comment seems to reveal something about the problem that is not included in the question. Please revise the question to explain what you mean be "handling slow takeoff." In addition, the need for torque measurement is not explained.

Answer (score 0):

To generate torque to hold a motor at standstill, any motor design can be used with a control system that includes a shaft position encoder.

A spring-set friction brake is has the advantage of maintaining position with no energy consumption. It does not require a shaft position controller or any other feedback from the mechanical system, but the stopping position is not controllable.

A servo design with a shaft position encoder has the advantage of stopping with high precision at a commanded position.

A stepper motor has less precision but does not require a shaft position encoder. A stepper motor may also have lower energy consumption when stopped.